# Book or short story identification: Children at adolesence turn into stinkers

Tags: story-identification

I've been wondering for years about a story I read a long time ago and haven't been able to find again. The premise is that certain people at adolescence (or thereabouts) begin to emit a aura that makes people hate them and want to hurt or kill them. The thing I remember is that they are called "stinkers". In the end the stinkers discover that they are all  psychokinetics.

The time frame for when I probably read it is as little as 45 years ago and perhaps as much as 60 years ago.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"[Invader On My Back](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20871102-invader-on-my-back)" ([isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9830)) by Philip E. High. Alien invaders have sent out telepathic signals that divide the human race. Some people are "Delinks" (short for delinquents) who are amoral criminals, some are "Norms" (normal people) and some are "Scuttlers", who are afraid of the sky. Turns out this is because they're the only ones who are able to see the devices in the sky that send out the signals (so they're afraid to look up) And of course the Stinkers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to get a copy, some of it looks similar, but I'm fairly sure at ten years old it's far too recent.  Still I've been know to be wrong before, so I'll check it out.   I remember the ending of the story included a group of the stinkers sitting on the ground with their legs folded and then flying off.

Comment: @ecmasonjr it was written in 1968

Comment: My mistake I was going  on the publication date from the websites I was looking on.  Did I mention I might be wrong?  Thanks for the information.

Comment: I've got a copy coming next week.   I guess I've forgotten most of the story in 50 years.

Comment: I acquired what may well be a fifty year old paperback and I have just finished reading it. It is indeed the book I asked about and I would like to thank you as I thoroughly enjoyed re-reading it again after all these years.

Comment: It appears that I have managed to confuse or perhaps to combine two stories in my mind and it was the other story I've been thinking about for a long time.  

The second is similar in that it involves outcasts of some type who in the end discover that they are psychokinetics and in the end sit cross legged and fly off.  The time frame would similarly be forty to sixty years ago.  

Any chance of using this request for that one as well or would it be better to make a new request?  Without the "stinker" reference, this one is much sketchier.