# 60s novel? Humanity has segregated in to classes of people. (by type, not race, or economic status, or gender)

Tags: story-identification, novel

Probably an old paperback Ace Sci-Fi novel from the 50s or 60s.

Modern world, but people have become evolved in different classes of people. (maybe 4-5 types?) I believe evolving at about puberty or late teens. I can only really remember 2.

The first maybe nicknamed "Scutlers" They are deeply afraid of the sky and won't look at it. If they do happen to look up they go into an epileptic type fit, and can become catatonic if they can't turn away. They avoid being outside, preferring to stay indoors, and when out doors, hurry along, hugging walls and covered up so they can't see the sky. [i.e. they scuttle along outside hugging the walls of buildings like a rat exposed outside.]

The second maybe called "Skunks" (or Stinkers). Shortly after puberty, people begin to feel irritated in their presence. Eventually turning to rage over time, and trying to kill them. Skunks have no choice but to get away from everyone and live like hermits not coming into contact with anyone.

Two scenes I remember from the book:

One of the protagonists is a Scuttler who is actually a high ranked policeman or government official. When he was a kid he loved the outdoors, but later when his parents realized he was a Scuttler, they let him watch videos from planes flying over the land so he could see the forests, mountains, lakes and rivers which he enjoyed seeing. But during one video he went into an epileptic fit from something he saw, and they stopped letting him see the videos.

This was a plot point, as later on, he started watching the old videos looking for what caused the fit.

Second, A young man has been kicked out of his home by his parents who can't stand him anymore, and his girlfriend broke up with him. So he leaves and goes to town to find a job and place to stay. At a diner where he stops to get something to eat, a patron at the crowded bar who he sits next to, tells him to get away from me. He moves to another spot and someone there says, get away from me. At that point one of the older patrons says something like "Hey folks, I think we have a skunk." Hunting skunks has become a favorite pastime, and is not illegal. VERY few skunks reach adulthood. They chase him outside and are about to kill him when they are confronted by an adult skunk driving a tank(?) who tells them to leave or die, and while their rage at the adult skunk is strong, he is still far enough away that they are still aware enough to realize he is dangerous and leave.

And while skunks are rare, there are very few adult skunks (a dozen?) as most are caught and killed after they change.

The Scuttler protagonist starts wondering what happens when two Skunks are near each other and contacts two of them to arrange a meeting between them. Skunks it turns out are immune to the effects of other Skunks. (Later one of them rescues the young man who's being chased by the mob.)

I think it turns out Skunks are psychic, Scuttlers can see what's in the sky that others can't see, and each of the other "types" I can't remember has an ability.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [Book or short story identification: Children at adolesence turn into stinkers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254755/book-or-short-story-identification-children-at-adolesence-turn-into-stinkers). The answer was [*Invader On My Back*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/20871102) by Philip E. High

Comment: From the book; _Besides rearranging the social structure of the race, the Troubles had also brought about sharp caste divisions which had nothing to do with wealth, heritage, color, creed, or any previously known cultural factor. These new castes were know by commonplace and often slightly vulgar terms of reference. There were, of course, the police, the Norms, the Scuttlers—every community has its Scuttlers—the Delinks, who could be subdivided into various categories, and the Stinkers._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be, as indicated in a comment, *[Invader on My Back](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9830)* by [Philip E. High](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_E._High), from 1968. It was published as an Ace Double together with *Destination: Saturn* by David Grinnell and Lin Carter.

[image: The covers of the Ace Double Destionation:Saturn / Invader on My Back. The former, on the left, has Saturn on a green background, in front of which stands a person wearing a crown, a red ornate jacket, white pants, and black boots, their arms crossed, next to which an alien creature looking like a 4-legged orange fuzz ball, its arms crossed as well. The latter has a giant black bird on a red background, towards which two spaceships are flying.]

Four main castes, with subdivisions.

> Besides rearranging the social structure of the race, the *Troubles* had also brought about sharp caste divisions which had nothing to do with wealth, heritage, colour, creed, or any previously known factor. All these castes were known by commonplace and often slightly vulgar terms of reference.
>
> There were, of course, the police, the Norms, the Scuttlers—every community has its Scuttlers—the Delinks, who could be sub-divided into various categories, and the Stinkers.

People try to kill Stinkers.

> The Stinkers were few and unique because a Stinker didn't develop into a Stinker until later adolescence. Once developed, he was exceedingly lucky if he survived a year—usually Stinkers ended up in some quiet place with a lot of holes in their backs.

Scuttlers can indeed see what's in the sky that others can't see.

> Toynbee, outwardly calm, looked up at him. "I want you," he said, "to pump me full of *Lessedrene*"
>
> [...]
>
> "What the hell do you want?"
>
> Toynbee grinned at him sadly and twistedly. "Something quite simple—I want to look at the sky."
>
> Waldron looked stunned. "But you're a Scuttler! The terror which the drug holds at bay will hit you like a club later. Besides, what *point* is there in it?"
>
> "The point is I might see something. Listen, most of this is classified but we suspect that a Scuttler can see something up there which others can't. Something which, if I were a normal, I should see instantly."

Toynbee, the Scuttler protagonist, used to love the outdoors. His parents created a setup that allowed him to travel, until one day he had an epileptic fit from something he saw.

> " [...] Listen, years ago, when I was much younger, I used to be mad on travel. Of course, I could never look at the sky but if a flyer was going to say, Fort Brisbane, my father used to fix things so I could go. Four terminals and an E/M viewer screen and I was away. Needless to say, everything was fixed so that I could only look but those trips used to be the joy of my life. They had the devil's own job to make me eat, I used to crouch at the screen watching the rivers and mountains rolling below us and I was lost, completely lost, until one day we, or rather I, ran into something."
>
> [...]
>
> "[...] We passed over an area of land which frightened me more than the sky had ever done. I had convulsions and it took three of the crew to hold me down before a medic could get close enough to inject a knock-out shot."

Comment: Yes, this is the book. I even had (or have?, would need to dig through my boxes of PB books to see if I still had this Ace Double) I mainly remember the Destination Saturn Cover, Forgot what was the other side novel.