# Sci-Fi book with alien telepathy as well as ‘stinkers.’

Tags: story-identification, aliens, telepaths

Probably written in late 60’s/early 70’s.

Earth has been taken over by telepathic aliens (like large bats - the protagonists find them in the Gibraltar stairs tunnel).

The aliens deal with any humans with latent psi abilities by inducing non-psi to find them to be ‘stinkers.’

The hero develops weapons/tools using a plastic than he finds can be manipulated by psi powers.

Comment: Duplicate of [Book or short story identification: Children at adolesence turn into stinkers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254755/book-or-short-story-identification-children-at-adolesence-turn-into-stinkers) and also [60s novel? Humanity has segregated in to classes of people. (by type, not race, or economic status, or gender](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/280012/60s-novel-humanity-has-segregated-in-to-classes-of-people-by-type-not-race).

Answer (score 4):

Based on aliens causing people to become "stinkers," this might be [*Invader on My Back*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9830) (1968) by Philip E. High

> Besides rearranging the social structure of the race, the *Troubles* had also brought about sharp caste divisions which had nothing to do with wealth, heritage, colour, creed, or any previously known factor. All these castes were known by commonplace and often slightly vulgar terms of reference.
>
> There were, of course, the police, the Norms, the Scuttlers—every community has its Scuttlers—the Delinks, who could be sub-divided into various categories, and the Stinkers.